# Count unique words with collections and dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a problem, I want to count the unique words from a dataframe, but unfortunately it only counts the first sentences.

```py
                          text
0  hello is a unique sentences
1         hello this is a test
2              does this works
```

```py
import pandas as pd
d = {
    "text": ["hello is a unique sentences",
             "hello this is a test", 
             "does this works"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


from collections import Counter

# Count unique words
def counter_word(text_col):
    print(len(text_col.values))
    count = Counter()
    for i, text in enumerate(text_col.values):
        print(i)
        for word in text.split():
            count[word] += 1
        return count

counter = counter_word(df['text'])
len(counter)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think simplier is join values by space, then split for words and count:

```
counter = Counter((' '.join(df['text'])).split())

print (counter)
Counter({'hello': 2, 'is': 2, 'a': 2, 'this': 2, 'unique': 1, 'sentences': 1, 'test': 1, 'does': 1, 'works': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to have a generator to feed to `Counter`:

```
from itertools import chain
counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, df['text'])))
```

output:

```
Counter({'hello': 2,
         'is': 2,
         'a': 2,
         'unique': 1,
         'sentences': 1,
         'this': 2,
         'test': 1,
         'does': 1,
         'works': 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier and more efficient to `stack` the words into a single column then use `pandas` `value_counts` to count them, instead of `Counter`:

```
df["text"].str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
```